# Why is my address calculation off?

Tags: assembly, x86

Why is the address in the two arrowed lines different?

I inserted the blue line in machine code in an .exe file and was expecting it to AND the value in the same address after the ADD instruction but apparently the AND take places in a different address according to disassembler.

[image]

I thought of it might be because an address offset but C5 - BE = 7 while F8 - EF = 9 so the offset does not even match and I have no idea what is going on between the address translation; how is the `0x0193A4EF` calculated when the address given in the machine code is `0x0131132A`?

Comment: Read up on "program counter-relative" addressing mode. `0x6291c5` (address of next instruction) + `0x0131132A` (offset provided in the instruction) = `0x0193A4EF` (intended target address).

Comment: Oh thanks, so it takes the starting address of the next instruction as base not the starting address of current instruction, it makes sense now thank you so much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using a RIP relative offset.
The disassembler is lying to you when decoding the instruction.
[The correct decoding is](https://www.onlinedisassembler.com):

```
66 01 1D 2A 13 31 01              add WORD PTR [rip+0x131132a],bx  
66 81 25 2A 13 31 01 7F FF        and WORD PTR [rip+0x131132a],0xff7f
```

Because RIP is always on the move you need to take `RIP` at the start of the **next** instruction and only than apply the offset: `6291BE + 7 + 131132A = 193A4EF` exactly as listed.
Because the next instruction is 9 bytes long and you are using the same offset to RIP you now need to add 9 bytes, so the target becomes: `6291C5 + 9 + 131132A = 193 A4F8`, again exactly as listed.

If you want both instructions to link to the same address you need to use a different RIP offset.

Always add the length of the instruction that uses RIP addressing to the start address of that instruction and then apply the offset.

I wonder why your assembler is not doing this automatically for you. Many assemblers have a `REL` pseudo addressing mode that fixes this very problem.
See e.g. [section 3.3 of the NASM Manual](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc3.html#section-3.3):

> In 64-bit mode, NASM will by default generate absolute addresses. The REL keyword makes it produce RIP-relative addresses.

The nice thing about `REL` is that you don't have to bother about calculating offsets yourself, just input the reference to whatever you're linking to after `REL`. The assembler will figure out the rest.

**Other remarks**
Whatever disassembler you are using to analyse your code is broken.
The `and` value is `FF7F`, because x64 is [little endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness). If it says `7FFF` in the instruction bytes you (and your disassembler) ought to know that the CPU will read FF7F because the least significant byte comes first.
Please ditch that piece of crap and get a decent disassembler to analyse your machine code.

Answer (score 1):

RIP-relative addressing counts from the end of the current instruction (start of the nextinstruction).

It makes sense if you think of a really simple CPU: It decodes an instruction, and *then* runs it.  By the time it's done decoding, the program counter (RIP) points to the end of the current instruction (start of next instruction), so the PC points to the next instruction while the current one runs.

Relative jumps are the same way, too.  (e.g. `jmp` with rel8=0 is a slow no-op).

Most architectures with relative jumps work this way, I think.  Also other architectures where the program counter is accessible.